# Grouping data and keeping only distinct values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to group and the following data in pgsql:

(TL;DR: Note the similar `target` entries for the two `print_names` *qz.M2* and *qz.M1*)

| print_name | target |
| --- | --- |
| qz.R | q3zA |
| qz.S | NULL |
| qz.M1 | q2zA |
| qz.M1 | q1zA |
| qz.M2 | q2zA |
| qz.M2 | q1zA |

in such a way that the distinct values of `target` are still in the result while the doubling of *qz.M** is avoided.

The result desired would therefore be:

| print_name | target |
| --- | --- |
| qz.R | q3zA |
| qz.S | NULL |
| qz.M1 | *q2zA* |
| qz.M2 | *q1zA* |

I tried:

```
SELECT min(target) FROM Table GROUP BY print_name;
```

However, this of course only yields one of two entries in `target`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you add your expected results for the sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is achievable without casing specific `print_name` if you want consistent answer.

```
SELECT t.print_name
    FROM Table t
    CASE 
       WHEN t.print_name = 'qz.M1' THEN max(t.target)
       WHEN t.print_name = 'qz.M2' THEN min(t.target)
       ELSE t.target END as Target
GROUP BY t.print_name
```

Answer (score -1):

Your desired results would seem to indicate just a simple aggregate:

```
select print_name, Max(target) target
from t
group by print_name
```

Note your sample data does not include any reliable method or sorting, `max()` will be based on *string* ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your swift help but this yields "q2zA" as `target` for both, qz.M1 and qz.M2. I understand from your answer I need to preprocess data in a different way to avoid the problem ...

Comment: Sorry yes I missed one was *q1* and *q2*. I think you need some more information in the question, what logic determines that qz.M1 gets *q2zA* and qz.M2 gets *q1zA*? It's not the easiest sample data to work with!